# How do I understand kernel oops error code?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, gcc10

I want to compile my linux kernel with GCC10.1 instead of GCC7.5 which I used before.

Sadly, the kernel does not boot fully on my device, I believe its sound that causes

Log: https://del.dog/raw/amyttunuva

kernel source: https://github.com/4u7157/kernel_common/tree/work

```
<4>[   29.583339]  [1:      eax-mixer: 1423] ------------[ cut here ]------------
<0>[   29.583350]  [1:      eax-mixer: 1423] Kernel BUG at ffffffc0003fd474 [verbose debug info unavailable]
<0>[   29.583358]  [1:      eax-mixer: 1423] Internal error: Oops - BUG: 96000061 [#1] PREEMPT SMP
<0>[   29.583369]  [1:      eax-mixer: 1423] exynos-snapshot: core register saved(CPU:1)
<0>[   29.583376]  [1:      eax-mixer: 1423] CPUMERRSR: 00000000190c0033, L2MERRSR: 000000001113ffb0
<0>[   29.583383]  [1:      eax-mixer: 1423] exynos-snapshot: context saved(CPU:1)
<6>[   29.583435]  [1:      eax-mixer: 1423] exynos-snapshot: item - log_kevents is disabled
<6>[   29.583452]  [1:      eax-mixer: 1423] TIF_FOREIGN_FPSTATE: 0, FP/SIMD depth 0, cpu: 0
<4>[   29.583462]  [1:      eax-mixer: 1423] CPU: 1 MPIDR: 80000001 PID: 1423 Comm: eax-mixer Tainted: G        W      3.18.140-00012-gdbe997b174c #1
```

How do I understand the error code?

eax-mixer is located in

```
sound/soc/samsung/eax-dma.c:299:                        kthread_run(eax_mixer_kthread, NULL, "eax-mixer");
sound/soc/samsung/eax-dma.c:845:                eax_mixer_kobj = kobject_create_and_add("eax-mixer", NULL);
```

Thank you!

Comment: This error is easy to understand as *verbose debug info unavailable*. So, enable more verbose information to be printed at Oops and then we can see what can be done.

Comment: @0andriy i have enabled the debugging. such as `CONFIG_DEBUG_INFO, CONFIG_DEBUG_KERNEL, CONFIG_DEBUG_BUGVERBOSE, CONFIG_KALLSYMS, CONFIG_DEBUG_BUGVERBOSE, etc` its still no info